# Finding the min and max of list - Syntax Error

Tags: warning-messages

```
findExtrema[list_] :=
 max = list[[1]], min = list[[1]], i = 2; While[i <= Length[list], 
 If[list[[i]] > max, max = list[[i]], 
  If[list[[i]] < min, min = list[[i]], null]]; i++]
```

Beginner project. Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: `MinMax[{1, 2, 3, 4}]`

Comment: welcome to MMA SE! seems like just a couple syntax errors: can't use commas to separate things like that outside of an enclosing expression (e.g. `{ ... }`), so you need `max = list[[1]]; min = list[[1]]; i = 2`. You also need to surround your whole definition (after `:=`) in parentheses, otherwise it will evaluate `findextrema[list_] := max = list[[1]]` and then move on (`:=` binds more tightly than `;`)

Comment: note, however, that while possible, it's not totally Mathematica-l to use global variables; it might be good experience to consider using `Module` to localize your variables and returning a list `{min, max}` (simply by having it be your final expression in a `;` sequence within `Module`, *not* by using `Return`, which probably doesn't do what you expect!) Also for experience check out `Scan` instead of using a `While` loop!

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250715/finding-min-and-max-of-list-syntax-error) which was closed because the answer is easily found in the documentation and answers had already been provided in the comments. You should have edited that question instead of making a new one.